# Positioning a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

Okay, here is my dilema, and I hope I can explain this well enough, because I don't have an example that I can post right now, but will work one up if I have to.

Say I have a div container (outer div) that has a header div,another content container inside of it (inner div) and a footer div.  So the outer div has a fixed width and height, and the inner div is fit to the width of the outer div but has a height that can overflow. because of this, the outer div has a vertical scrollbar to scroll it's inner content (header, container and footer) up and down, and the inner div container has content that can have a variable height, but because of the fixed width needs a scrollbar to move it's content left and right.

The dilemma in this scenario is that at times the inner content overflows the outer div such that I have to scroll down to get to the scrollbar of the inner content area to move it left and right.  Is there a way that I can put a scrollbar at the bottom of the outer div that would control the inner div content's left and right movement, but not move the header and footer of the inner content of the outer div?

Hope I explained that well enough.

Dan B

Comment: You know, you could probably have written up an easy to read example in the time it took you to explain your code in words.

Comment: Please visit jsFiddle.net and make a example with the HTML you have in mind so we can help you better.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that I built partially with code I am working with.
http://jsfiddle.net/nbeuko3v/embedded/result/
As you can see there is a vertical scrollbar on the right that moves the header and footer paginators and content table.  If you scroll down to just above the footer paginator, you see the horizontal scrolbar that moves the content of the data table left and right. I need a JS trick to put a scrollbar at the bottom of the main container div that will scroll the content of the data table left and right, but NOT the header and footer paginators.

Comment: @DanBemowski is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/6108f3pr/ ?

Comment: @sergio, Not exactly. Basically I do not want to have to scroll down to get to the horizontal scroll bar.  Maybe there is a way to do this through CSS, but I know there are scripts for doing custom scrollbars using mootools/javascript.  I was thinking that there may be a way to link a scrollbar that stays static to the bottom of the outer div to control the inner div content.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution you're looking for is the problem I'm having... in regards to headers in tables.  The header will not scroll left and right along with the inner content and I need it to.

Not real sure about your problem but you might try working with headers and footers in tables.  I swiped/borrowed some code from here to learn about fixed table headers:

http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

Works great until I get a vertical scroll bar.  Then the header stays fixed and won't move with the rest of the columns.  I haven't tried working with table footers yet...

Cheers,
Jeff

Comment: Not quite what I wanted Jeff.  See my comment to my original post.