# How to move the scrollbar position in a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a costume admin dashboard for my SPA project. I have the following codes for sidebar section:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo_content">
            <div class="logo">
                <i class='bx bxl-c-plus-plus'></i>
                <div class="logo_name">CodeX</div>
            </div>
            <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="items-list">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bxs-grid-alt'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
                        <span class="links_name">User</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            .
            .
            <-- uls come here -->
            .
            .
            .
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar .items-list{
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
    .sidebar ul{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .sidebar ul li{
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 5px;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    
    .sidebar ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 12px;
        transition: all .4s ease;
    }
    
    .sidebar ul li a:hover{
        color: #11101d;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    .sidebar ul li a i{
        height: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
```

The styled page is:

[image: Final result]

I want to move the scrollbar to the right edge of the sidebar. Currently, there is some gap between the sidbar edge and the scrollbar.
I have studied some related questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889449/possible-to-move-scrollbar-position) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987180/positioning-a-scrollbar), but I could not implement them in my own problem.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by modifying these styles:

```
.sidebar ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #11101d;
    padding: 6px 2px;
}
```

[image]